# Jquery mobile style not getting applied during ajax

Tags: jquery-mobile

Am trying to load some section of a page using ajax in jquery mobile and then append it to the dom. The styles of jquery mobile is not getting applied.Checked and found out that there should be .trigger('create') method that should be called. But, it is adding some empty space.

Am doing the below thing.

```
$.ajax({
 url : pageName,
 dataType : "html",
 success : function(data) {
  $("#score").html(data);
  $("#score").trigger("create");
 }
});
```

Is there something wrong in this. Please help.

---

```
It does not seem to work. This is the below structure after the listview is inserted into the dom 

<div id="newssection">
   <ul data-role="listview">
  <li class="load" data-icon="false">
   <a id="newsLink" rel="external" href="NewsDetail.html">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">ABC</div>
   </a>
  </li>
   <li class="load" data-icon="false">
    <a id="newsLink" rel="external" href="NewsDetail.html">
   <div class="ui-grid-a">ABC</div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="footerContainer">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to append? post your HTML markup pls.

Comment: am trying to append something like this: 

 <ul data-role="listview">
  <li class="load" data-icon="false"><a href="NewsDetail.html" rel="external"
   id="newsLink">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
     <div class="ui-block-a news">
      <h1>Bangalore v Pune,IPL 2013,Bangalore</h1>
      <p>
       <strong> Ruthless Gayle hammers fastest </strong>
      </p>
     </div>
     <div class="ui-block-b news">
      <img src="../images/156349.3.jpg" alt="o" class="newsImage" />
     </div>
    </div>
  </a></li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Credit goes to [@Gajotres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848600/gajotres)

Use `$('[data-role=lisview]').listview().listview('refresh')`.

```
$.ajax({
 url : pageName,
 dataType : "html",
 success : function(data) {
  $("#score").html(data);
  $('[data-role=lisview]').listview().listview('refresh');
 }
});
```

Comment: getting this error:cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: Omar was correct, this will fix your problem: $("#score").listview().listview('refresh');

Comment: Thanks. Now it works but I have added an id to the ui tag. And then called ("#newId").listview().listview('refresh')." #score " is id of the div tag.It is working now. But, it is getting overlapped with other content in page. Noticed that .ui-content .ui-listview, .ui-panel-inner > .ui-listview {
    margin: -15px;
} is being added by the framework. If I disable this margin value, it is working fine. Also, i have one more div tag below the ul tag. Though it is getting added to the DOM. It is not visible. Looks like it is also getting overlapped.

Comment: Would also like to know why this refresh functionality is not handled by the framework itself, since it works mostly on AJAX mode. Any specific reason?

Comment: Gajotres/Omar, Would also like to know why this refresh functionality is not handled by the framework itself, since it works mostly on AJAX mode. Any specific reason?

Comment: I have a button inside the #score div. Am adding the button using AJAX. How should we refresh the button. Is it like this?                      $("#score").find('.viewbutton').attr('data-role', 'button').end().trigger('create');

Comment: try `$('.viewbutton').attr('data-role', 'button').button().trigger('create');`